# Using Laravel Mentions (at.JS and Laravel) to return A username and their ID

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I'm currently building a comment system and would like to include the ability to mention users and tag them, subsequently I would like the tag to have a link to their profile (In this example, it's just /profile/{id})

I am currently using Laravel Mentions to generate the auto filled list from my Users Model. I'm doing it like:

```
function enableMentions(elem, type, column) {

$(elem).atwho({
    at: "@",
    limit: 5,
    displayTpl: '<li><span>${name}</span></li>',
    insertTpl: '<a href="/profile/${name}" data-type="mentionable" data-id="${id}" data-name="${name}">${name}</a>',
    callbacks: {
        remoteFilter: function(query, callback) {
            if (query.length <= 1) return;

            $.getJSON("/api/mentions/" + type, {
                q: query,
                c: column
            }, function(data) {
                callback(data);
            });
        }
    }
});
}

// My api/mentions route: Route::get('/api/mentions/{type}', 'ApiController@index');

//My api controller:
    public function index($type, Request $request)
{
    try {
        $resultColumns = [];
        $query = $request->get('q');
        $column = $request->get('c');

        $model = app()->make(config('mentions.' . $type));
        $records = $model->where($column, 'LIKE', "%$query%")
            ->get();
        foreach ($records as $record) {
            $resultColumns[] = $record->$column;
        }
        return response()->json($resultColumns);
    } catch (\ReflectionException $e) {
        return response()->json('Not Found', 404);
    }
}

And finally, initializing the at.js
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
 enableMentions("#mention-commentContent", "users", "Username");
 });
 </script>
 <div contentEditable="true" id="mention-commentContent" class="user-form" name="commentContent" type="text"></div>
```

I'm confused on how I can modify the above to return the username and the ID assigned to them, that way I can change the ${name} to ${id} and have it link through to their profile, right?

Answer (score 0):

This package may help [Laravel Mentions](https://github.com/Pandahisham/Laravel-Mentions) or [this](https://github.com/unicodeveloper/laravel-mentions) .

The basic idea is getting the usernames from the database via JSON , here is how they are using it in [laracasts](https://laracasts.com/):

```
$("textarea#body").atwho({
            at: "@", limit: 5, callbacks: {
                remoteFilter: function (t, e) {
                    t.length <= 2 || $.getJSON("/api/users", {q: t}, function (t) {
                        e(t)
                    })
                }
            }
        })
```